# How to show date format (yyyy/mm/dd) in ListPointPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, date-and-time, time-series

I have `data1`, whose first column is, in fact, the date (i.e. number of days from **1900/1/1**). I then create a 3D plot as below:-

```
data1 = {{42219, 33, 71}, {42218, 35, 72}, {42217, 36, 72.5}, {42216, 36.5, 73}};
ListPointPlot3D[data1]
```

[image]

As you can see, 42216 and 42219 etc. are shown on the axis label. But I want to show the date **yyyy/mm/dd** instead. Thus I tried to convert data1's first column into the date format:-

```
data1[[All, 1]] = DateObject[{1900, 1, 1}] + data1[[All, 1]]*Quantity[1, "Days"];
data1
ListPointPlot3D[data1]
```

I am successful to convert the format but failed to create the plot. I obtained this error as output:-

```
Last::nolast: {} has zero length and no last element.
```

How can I show the date format in the axis? Many thanks!

Comment: You want to change the `Ticks`  so try `tickspecs1 = Map[{#, DateObject[{1900, 1, 1}] + #*Quantity[1, "Days"]} &, data1[[All, 1]] ];` then `ListPointPlot3D[data1, Ticks -> {tickspecs1, Automatic, Automatic}]` although a date string format would look better.

Comment: Just saw the format you want the ticks in so try `Map[{#, DateString[
    DateObject[{1900, 1, 1}] + #*Quantity[1, "Days"], {"Year", "/", 
     "Month", "/", "Day"}]} &, data1[[All, 1]] ]` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
  data1 = {{42219, 33, 71}, {42218, 35, 72}, {42217, 36, 72.5}, {42216, 
    36.5, 73}};
tickspecs1 = Map[{#, DateString[ DateObject[{1900, 1, 1}] + #*Quantity[1, "Days"], {"Year", "/", "Month", "/", "Day"}]} &, data1[[All, 1]] ];
ListPointPlot3D[data1, Ticks -> {tickspecs1, Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image]